# React with typescript jquery import isn't working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a bootstrap plugin called bootstrap toggle
I've already downloaded the css and js scripts through npm but it requires jQuery

I've also downloaded jQuery and it's types using
`npm install jquery` and `npm install @types/jquery`

I've tried importing jQuery but when I used `import 'jquery'` it returns `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

you are importing jquery to use it, but by doing so jquery will not expose itself to the (global) window object! So we can fix this problem by exposing the jquery object ourselves!

simply include the following code before using the global jquery variable:

```
import * as jquery from "jquery";

Object.assign(global, {
    $: jquery,
    jQuery: jquery,
});
```

Now jquery is exposed as `$` and `jQuery` globally.